# How can I suppress individual BizTalk warnings in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: visual-studio, warnings, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

We are currently using BizTalk 2006 R2 to build Enterprise Integration solutions. We use BizTalk maps extensively, but when you build a solution in Visual Studio 2005, it produces the following warning against maps:

> Warning Double-click here to show/hide compiler links.

In my opinion, these are not real warnings and can be ignored, but I don't like that strategy because ignoring warnings is a bad habit to get into.

Using a \nowarn property does not seem to be an option because the message does not have an associated number.

Also, when the project is built using a build script the warning disappears, suggesting that this is a feature of Visual Studio rather than a real compiler warning.

So I was wondering if there is a way to suppress this type of warning in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to suppress these for BizTalk projects.  BizTalk gurus just learn to ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /nowarn option to suppress warnings.

See [MSDN: /nowarn (Suppress Specified Warnings) (C# Compiler Options)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3(VS.80).aspx).

Comment: A good answer, but doesn't quite fix my problem. I've updated the question accordingly. Thanks, AL.

Comment: Dead link. Page removed.